# mongo count operations with $ne query are not covered

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I'm running mongo 3.2.11 (WiredTiger). I have a collection with a field containing ISODates, and I noticed a significant difference between queries of this form:

```
db.my_collection.count({ my_field: { $ne: null } })
```

and this form:

```
db.my_collection.count({ my_field: { $gt: ISODate('2010-01-01') } })
```

When I run explain I see that the first type of query yields an `IXSCAN` stage and the second type yields a `COUNT_SCAN` stage. My guess is that `COUNT_SCAN` queries are covered (so they don't need to fetch documents from disk), while `IXSCAN` queries need to pull data from disk.

If my understanding is correct, does anyone know in general why `{$ne: null}` can't be covered? I'd like to understand the rule and whether it's likely to change since I use `{$ne: null}` all the time (when something more specific but less elegant IMO like `{$gt: some_really_early_date}` would work as well).

Comment: I'm just curious. Although not exact replacement does it change anything if you use logical operator and `db.my_collection.count({ my_field: { $not: {$type:12 } }})` instead and also this variant which I'm positive  `db.my_collection.count({ my_field: { $exists: true}})` will use the `COUNT_SCAN`

Comment: @SagarReddy good question, I tried `$exists: true` but it shows `IXSCAN` in the query planner. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `$type: 12` though (did you mean the null type or the date type?)

Comment: Sorry `$type: 10`. I'm not expecting that to work anyways. It will do IXSCAN based from docs. I was expecting the `$exists` to work though.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: it's a mongodb bug!
Please see the following JIRA issue, created in 2015 already but still unresolved in the backlog: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18861

You may vote for it to get it fixed eventually.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality operator $ne is not very selective since it often matches a large portion of the index. As a result, in many cases, a $ne query with an index may perform no better than a $ne query that must scan all documents in a collection.

Comment: I don't think that's relevant here - the two forms of the query I showed above both yield the same count in my case

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem is with `$in` (see the example). You can find [the issue here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27822).

Example (`IXSCAN` is used instead of `COUNT_SCAN`):

```
collection.count({
  thing: {
    $in: [ // for a single entry it uses COUNT_SCAN
      ObjectId('54e1b392cf53590c4f3dd77c'),
      ObjectId('557ff02b83f641960fef49da')
    ]
  }
})
```